# JQuery, check if something is open and close it

Tags: jquery, if-statement, slidetoggle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".firstUL").css('display','none');

    $(".matches").click(function(){
        $(".firstUL").slideToggle();
    });

    if ($(".firstUL").is(":visible")){

        $(".closeMatches").click(function(){
            $(".firstUL:visible").slideToggle();
        });
    };
});
```

Click `.matches` and `.firstUL` slidetoggle.
check if `.firstUL` is visible and `.closeMatches` can close/slidetoggle `.firstUL`.

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: can you share a live demo with `html` and etc..?

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's visible.

```
$("#ID").is(':visible');
```

Check if it's hidden.

```
$("#ID").is(':hidden');
```

**Note:** But in your case you are using `.firstUL` class selector, which means there are more than element with the same class exist. And there is a possibility that all of them are not `hidden` or `visible` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `if part` of your code outside `$(document).ready` function.

When you are using a code inside `$(document).ready` function the code is executed when the DOM completely loads. now when you are checking whether the firstUL is visible or not from inside the `$(document).ready` function the js finds it hidden always. Thats because the element becomes visible only when you are clicking the matches button. but the if part won't execute after the matches button is clicked as it will run again only when the page reloads. Hence your if statement always finds it hidden.

**working snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".firstUL").css('display', 'none');

  $(".matches").click(function() {
    $(".firstUL").slideToggle();
  });


});
 $('.firstUL').ready(function(){

  $(".closeMatches").click(function() {
    $(".firstUL").css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="firstUL">.firstUL</div>
<button class="matches">matches</button>
<button class="closeMatches">closeMatches</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please format your code and perhaps put the if inside the load handler - it does not look right

Comment: @neophyte. I see your code works here, but when I copy and test your code only the first part (the slidetoggle) works. I can't get the second part to work.

Comment: @LarsJensen do you have more than one element with `firstUL` class?

Comment: let me know if it helps

Comment: @neophyte, sorry for the late respons. In the second argument I just went with the slideUp function, and that works. Thanks anyway.